# Why does the thirteen.org date library return dates in the same year for a 53-week year (for week 53)?

Tags: java

Using the https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra library.

When computing the first Sunday of the month, given week number and year, I noticed that if I used 2018 and week 53, I get as the result the first Sunday 2018-12-02.

Yet, 2018 is not a 53-week year so I am wondering if I'm doing something wrong or perhaps there's something special about 2018? I didn't see that the week start date or other 53-week conditions were met, but I could have missed something.

In other tests like 2011 (also not a and week 53-week year), the date logic wraps the result as expected to 2012-01-01 (the first Sunday in the first week of the next year).

Years 2020, 2015, and 2019 (all 53-week years) display the result value as expected in December of the respective year.

Here is the code:

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.of(year, weekNumber);
//Get the date of the first day of that week.
LocalDate ld = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
// Use a TemporalAdjuster to get nth day-of-week of that month date’s month.
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 1 , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
//  TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth();
LocalDate firstSunday = ld.with( ta ) ;
return firstSunday.toString();
```

Suggestions?

Comment: "the first Sunday of the month, given week number and year" doesn't make sense to me. How do you calculate "the month" when given a week number and a year?

Comment: @Sweeper https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date is an existing thing.

Comment: @tevemadar I know it is a thing, but how do you get "the month" from a week number and a year? You would also need a day-of-week to figure that out, right? A week can span at most two months.

Comment: Please check out the library's documentation. This library was created specifically for these kinds of data calculations.

Comment: It's not about what the library does - it's about an ill-specified requirement. What *exactly* do you mean by "the first Sunday of the month, given week number and year"? Different parts of the same week might be in different months, so which month are you interested in, in that case?

Comment: Asking the library which is the first Sunday for week 53 in 2018, when 2018 isn't a 53-week year, should wrap to the next year's Sunday, right? Perhaps I misunderstood your comment above, but December 2, 2018 is all in the same month. Other non 53-week years I've tested years warp the first Sunday to the next Sunday (in the next year) for week = 53. I will post my actual code above.

Comment: Your question is much clearer after the edit. Thank you. It is now very clear how you are calculating this, namely using Monday of the week to determine "the month".

Comment: Apologies, I should have included the code to begin with. Thank you for your excellent reply (and solution) below. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [`YearWeek.of`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html#of(int,int)) does:

> Obtains an instance of YearWeek from a week-based-year and week.
>
> If the week is 53 and the year does not have 53 weeks, week one of the following year is selected.

Therefore, for `(2018, 53)`, it selects the first week of 2019, because 2018 only has 52 weeks. This is the week starting from 2018-12-31 and ending at 2019-01-06.

You then get the Monday of this week, which is 2018-12-31, and adjusts this date to the first Sunday of the month. "The month" here being December, you get 2018-12-02 as a result.

Similarly, for `(2011, 53)`, you get the first week of 2012 because 2011 only has 52 weeks. But unlike 2019, this is the week starting from 2012-01-02 and ending at 2012-01-08, so there is no problem.

So what's "special" about 2018? Its last week ends before the last day of the year, I suppose? This causes the first week of the next year to start in December.

Comment: Good answer, except that first sentence’ clause “it selects the first week of 2019” is confusing. 2018-W53 is the last week of 2018.

Comment: That bumping to the next week is what needs more explanation in your prose. Your second to the last paragraph needs the same kind of additional explanation.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but I tried editing anyway. Better now?